# Cannot compare xs:string to xs:integer

Tags: java, xpath, talend, saxon

Currently running a code on `Talend` and it throws up this error

> net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot compare xs:string to
>   xs:integer    at
>   net.sf.saxon.expr.GeneralComparison.typeCheck(GeneralComparison.java:255)

when the saxon 9 is added to the configuration but when its removed it works fine. Any ideas why its interfering with the xpath

Comment: I don't know the cause but you can try to cast before you compare, e.g. `xs:integer($var1) eq 100`

Comment: Presumably it's preferring the Saxon XPath classes to the default ones. I had a problem where is did something strange and crashed an otherwise working route, just by putting saxon9 jars on the classpath. I know that saxon won't compare a string with an integer, so you do need the cast that @wp78de suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Saxon, precisely, did you add to the Configuration?

Prior to Saxon 9.6, the Saxon jar file included a manifest indicating that it was a JAXP XPath service provider. As a result, any application code trying to create an XPath provider using the JAXP factory method (`XPathFactory.newInstance()`) would pick up Saxon if it happened to be on the classpath. Unfortunately the JAXP API is not sufficiently rigorous that all XPath providers are interchangeable; in particular, you have no way of saying that you need an XPath 1.0 engine rather than an XPath 2.0 or XPath 3.1 engine. As a result (and as I am speculating has happened here), an application that was assuming XPath 1.0 behaviour (such as automatic casting of integers to strings in a comparison) might fail because the presence of Saxon on the classpath meant it was actually running XPath 2.0 or later.

To solve this problem releases from Saxon 9.6 onwards no longer declare themselves to be XPath service providers, and you must now instantiate Saxon directly rather than through the JAXP factory mechanism. But if you're using a version earlier than 9.6, the problem will still be there.

You can find out which version you have got by running

```
java -cp saxon9.jar net.sf.saxon.Version
```

Comment: Thank you! I had saxon 9.3he and downloaded 9.8he instead and the issue seems resolved.

Comment: i was able to make the change in studio in the configuration however it doesn't change it in runtime it seems. Is there a way to upgrade saxon on the system completely? Bceause other interfaces are using saxon 9.6 but have no error only the one which I changed is using 9.8. could that be casuing a clash?

Comment: To replace all instances of old Saxon releases anywhere in the system by the latest release you first need to find all these instances, and they can be buried very deep within any installed application, so no, it's not easy. There may also be applications that depend on an earlier release for some reason, e.g. they use internal classes/methods that have since been replaced.